# BigQuery row_number to remove duplicates

Tags: google-bigquery, mysql-8.0

I want to keep only the ID with the latest timestamp from the table, is there a more optimal and efficient way to solve the problem

a query that I tried

```
SELECT * except(row_number)
FROM (
  SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER()
          OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
          row_number
  FROM employees 

)
WHERE row_number = 1
```

employees table:

```
    ID    NAME  DEPARTMENT   UPDATED_AT
    1     James IT           2019-05-21 12:13:14
    1     James IT           2019-05-21 12:14:14 
    1     James IT           2019-05-21 12:18:14
    2     Pam   HR           2019-05-26 13:18:14
    2     Pam   HR           2019-05-26 14:18:14
    3     David IT           2019-06-22 14:18:14
    3     David IT           2019-06-23 12:18:14
```

result:

```
    ID    NAME  DEPARTMENT   UPDATED_AT
    1     James IT           2019-05-21 12:18:14
    2     Pam   HR           2019-05-26 14:18:14
    3     David IT           2019-06-23 12:18:14
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing the `ORDER BY` clause in your subquery statement.

```
WITH
  DATA AS (
    SELECT
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY UPDATED_AT DESC) AS _row,
       *
    FROM
      employees )
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(_row)
FROM
  DATA
WHERE
  _row = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM employees 
WHERE TRUE
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY UPDATED_AT DESC) = 1
```